# How to change the geometry of main window programmatically at run time w.r.t QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qt5, qtquick2

I have Qt Creator 2.6.1.
I created simple Qt Qucik 2.0 project from project templates and changed main.qml file on this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    color: "red"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: parent.height = 180
    }
}
```

If i will click on rectangle it should be reduced in half. And it is occured, but window is not reduced.

What is a best solution, if i want that main window must repeat geometry of main qml rectangle?

UPDATE. One solution was found. See Amit Tomar answer. But is exist more easier solution, for example, using [QtQuick 5.0: Qt Quick Window QML Types](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qmlmodule-qtquick-window2-qtquick-window-2.html) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are changing the geometry of your qml, not the Viewer. To do so:

1. Geometry of the viewer can be changed using the QmlApplicationViewer object you would have created in your main function.
2. But that object is in C++, so you need to expose a C++ function to qml, and call that function on click of this button.

Steps:

1. Create a class and store the Application viewer object created in the main.cpp, inside this class for further calls.
2. [Expose a function in this class to qml.](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtbinding.html#calling-functions) This function shall be able to modify the size using the application viewer object stored in the class.
3. On click of qml rectangle, call this function.

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"
#include "qdeclarativecontext.h"

#include "myclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QmlApplicationViewer *viewer = new QmlApplicationViewer();

    MyClass myClassObject(viewer);
    viewer->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myViewer", &myClassObject);
    viewer->setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer->setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/untitled/main.qml"));
    viewer->showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

myclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"

class MyClass : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:

    MyClass( QmlApplicationViewer * p ) { internalViewer = p ; }
    Q_INVOKABLE void viewerResize(int x, int y, int length, int breadth)

     {
       internalViewer->setGeometry(internalViewer->x(),internalViewer->y(),length,breadth);
     }

private:

    QmlApplicationViewer *internalViewer;
 };

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        text: "Hello World"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:
        {
            myViewer.viewerResize(0,0,110,110)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is work! But is exist more easier solution? For example, using "QtQuick 5.0: Qt Quick Window QML Types"?

Answer (score 2):

The **ApplicationWindow** desktop control gives you the window sizing capability you want:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: container
    width: 360
    height: 360
    color: "Red"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: container.height = 180
    }
}
```

Note: I could not use just `parent.height` in `onClicked` -- I had to refer to the window by id.